# Is it possible to get a coredump or stacktrace in windows when c# application crash because of 3rd unmanaged library

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have an application that is using some (probably managed, not sure here) c# wrapper for unmanaged c++ library (in this case gtk#).

When the application crash because of some problem inside this unmanaged code in the c++ library, my application crash with

"binary.exe has stopped working

Windows is looking for a solution for this problem..."

My problem is that it seems to me that this kind of problem can't be catched as an exception by any way, because it is caused by the unmanaged code. (I am catching all kinds of exceptions everywhere)

My question is: is there a way to effectively analyze this crash somehow? In linux the crashed mono will generate a coredump and print a lot of debugging information into terminal, which can be useful. But this is not a case in windows. Is there a way to get a coredump or at least a stack trace of my application from a moment of crash so that I can find out on which line of my managed code (before calling the unmanaged code that caused the crash) my application crashed?

Comment: I think there must be a better method, but last time I had this problem I added lots of debug.print statements to my code and looked which one was executed right before the crash.

Comment: Yes this is what I am doing now :)

Comment: I googled this lnk: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/d6efa2ce-4a8f-486f-a154-b61968c12308/

looks promising ;)